# How do I resolve this error when upgrading to 2019 R1

Tags: acumatica

I'm upgrading an older version (6.1) to 2019 R1 (19.100.0022) and an old section of code is giving me an error that I cannot understand.  Here's the relevant code - which is an attribute:

```
[ActiveProjectTask(typeof(EPExpenseClaimSummary.projectID), BatchModule.EP, DisplayName = "Project Task")]
[PXDefault]
public virtual int? TaskID
{
```

The problem is that there seems to be something wrong with the 'BatchModule.EP' parameter.  Here's the error I get:

```
ProjectTaskAttribute does not support the given module.
Parameter name: Module
Actual value was EP.
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: ProjectTaskAttribute does not support the given module.
Parameter name: Module
Actual value was EP.]
PX.Data.PXGraph.CreateInstance(Type graphType, String prefix) +1017
PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.f(Type A_0) +560
PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.g(Type A_0) +195
PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.get_DataGraph() +396
User_PageTitle.InitAuditMenu() +591
User_PageTitle.Page_InitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +71
System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
System.Web.UI.Page.OnInitComplete(EventArgs e) +141
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean 
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2203
```

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: I have a feeling you might be compiling against older Acumatica reference because EPExpenseClaimSummary was removed in newer versions. This alone won't solve your issues but if the customization is a compiled library you should make sure you reference the latest Acumatica DLL (PX.Objects.dll, PX.Common.dll etc...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't locate the relevant release note but I'm almost certain this is a breaking change introduced by newer versions. Only `BatchModule.EA` will be allowed in that context, for all practical purpose it seems to have replaced `BatchModule.EP`.

More concerning is `EPExpenseClaimSummary` which was removed so I think some refactoring will be necessary here because the module was re-implemented. You can get inspiration from the new DAC EPExpenseClaim (summary) and EPExpenseClaimDetails (details). I think the `ActiveProjectTask` attribute should be replaced by `EPExpenseAllowProjectTask` attribute (exemple in source code below).

The TaskID field has been moved from Summary to Details so you can't re-use your current logic. This means task are now assigned per detail records instead of being assigned to a single header record changing the relationship from 1-1 to 1-x. Also project was renamed to contract. The most relevant fields for you would be `EPExpenseClaimDetails.ContractID` and `EPExpenseClaimDetails.TaskID`:

```
    #region ContractID
    public abstract class contractID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref = "Contract.ContractID"/> project or contract</see>, which should be specified if the 
    /// employee incurred the expenses while working on a particular project or contract. 
    /// You can select a project or contract only if the Project Management or Contract Management feature, 
    /// respectively, is enabled on the Enable/Disable Features (CS100000) form.
    /// </summary>
    [PXDBInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Project/Contract")]
    [PXDimensionSelector(ContractAttribute.DimensionName,
                        typeof(Search2<Contract.contractID,
                                       LeftJoin<EPEmployeeContract,
                                                On<EPEmployeeContract.contractID, Equal<Contract.contractID>,
                                                And<EPEmployeeContract.employeeID, Equal<Current2<employeeID>>>>>,
                                       Where<Contract.isActive, Equal<True>,
                                             And<Contract.isCompleted, Equal<False>,
                                             And<Where<Contract.nonProject, Equal<True>,
                                                       Or2<Where<Contract.baseType, Equal<CTPRType.contract>,
                                                       And<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.contractManagement>>>,
                                                       Or<Contract.baseType, Equal<CTPRType.project>,
                                                       And2<Where<Contract.visibleInEA, Equal<True>>, 
                                                       And2<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.projectModule>,
                                                       And2<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>,
                                                       And<Where<Contract.restrictToEmployeeList, Equal<False>,
                                                       Or<EPEmployeeContract.employeeID, IsNotNull>>>>>>>>>>>>,
                                       OrderBy<Desc<Contract.contractCD>>>),
                         typeof(Contract.contractCD),
                         typeof(Contract.contractCD),
                         typeof(Contract.description),
                         typeof(Contract.customerID),
                         typeof(Contract.status),
                         Filterable = true,
                         ValidComboRequired = true,
                         CacheGlobal = true,
                         DescriptionField = typeof(Contract.description))]
    [ProjectDefault(BatchModule.EA, AccountType = typeof(expenseAccountID))]

    public virtual int? ContractID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region TaskID
    public abstract class taskID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="PMTask">project task</see> to which the expenses are related. 
    /// This box is available only if the Project Management feature is enabled on the Enable/Disable Features (CS100000) form.
    /// </summary>
    ///
    [PXDefault(typeof(Search<PMTask.taskID, Where<PMTask.projectID, Equal<Current<contractID>>, And<PMTask.isDefault, Equal<True>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [EPExpenseAllowProjectTaskAttribute(typeof(EPExpenseClaimDetails.contractID), BatchModule.EA, DisplayName = "Project Task")]
    [PXUIEnabled(typeof(Where<contractID, IsNotNull, And<Selector<contractID, Contract.baseType>, Equal<CTPRType.project>>>))]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<contractID, IsNull, Or<Selector<contractID, Contract.baseType>, NotEqual<CTPRType.project>>>, Null>, taskID>))]
    [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<taskID>.IsRelatedTo<PMTask.taskID>))]
    public virtual int? TaskID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
```